# Apple Wallet: Device not registering to receive push notification for a pass

Tags: c#, ios, passkit, apple-wallet

Recently, I've managed to create a pass with `WebServiceUrl` and `AuthenticationToken` in order to subscribe for future changes. Since I'm in active development I used `http://localhost:5000/passes` as a `WebServiceUrl`.

Created pass is correctly loaded in *iOS Simulator*, but when I try to add it to the wallet, device won't make a call in order to register for notifications using my API (**POST** request to `{webServiceURL}/{version}/devices/ {deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/{passTypeIdentifier}/{serialNumber}`) as it should, according to the docs:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html and
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html.

I've checked *iOS Simulator Console* that shows no signs of such a request.

Some interesting observations worth mentioning:

- my first successfully created pass made this device registration call, but since that moment, it was never done again
- device unregistering call (among other calls) is made every time pass is deleted from the wallet. I can see it in *iOS Simulator Console* and my *API* logs so apparently `WebServiceUrl` is valid and usable.

Comment: running into the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same here. Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided Apple PassKit docs states:

> NOTE: Test updates on a device; the iOS Simulator app doesn’t register for push notifications.

So basically that's it but what really bakes my noodle is that I'm pretty sure, that my first run of a test pass using iOS simulator made that call. Anyway, I ended up testing it on a physical device. That's it.

Comment: i just spent few hours trying understang why i couldn't see the post but i could see the delete one... thanks.....fjdasfsdoffsdkfdfkdafkj